# Vaadin23 application won't load - script vaadin-bundle-xxx.cache.js 404 not found

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I'm working on a Vaadin application running under tomcat in a WAR file.

I'm trying to simply upgrade it from Vaadin 22 to Vaadin 23.

It was loading reliably with Vaadin 22 but now it fails to load with Vaadin 23.

The WAR file is named `pcom.war` and within it `web.xml` contains:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PCOM</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pcom/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Therefore, the URL I trying to load the web application from, and from which Vaadin is failing to load successfully, is: `http://localhost:8080/pcom/pcom/`.

The `index.html` generated by Vaadin in `META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/index.html` in `pcom.war` contains (line breaks added for clarity):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
<style>body, #outlet {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }</style>
<script defer="defer" src="VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-67fde5fb08b0f134e867.cache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outlet"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the `src="VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-...` relative URL. This is correct, relative to `index.html` as it sits within the `META-INF` contents of `pcom.war`:

```
        0  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/
       79  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/
        0  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/config/
     1844  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/config/flow-build-info.json
     1658  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/config/stats.json
        0  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/
        0  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/
        0  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/
  1051904  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-1-cfc74d1f13c51748c7ba.cache.js
   259593  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-1-cfc74d1f13c51748c7ba.cache.js.gz
   607425  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-2-737c0b4498b03051df61.cache.js
   158040  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-2-737c0b4498b03051df61.cache.js.gz
    67025  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-3-460383d2eeb67dbda1eb.cache.js
    23477  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-3-460383d2eeb67dbda1eb.cache.js.gz
    27991  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-4-9ba06ea1fd5a6da385f4.cache.js
     8040  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-4-9ba06ea1fd5a6da385f4.cache.js.gz
     3518  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-5-a21e874ef30c99e3575f.cache.js
     1480  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-5-a21e874ef30c99e3575f.cache.js.gz
   138893  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-6-5710b84bf57453285225.cache.js
    46654  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-6-5710b84bf57453285225.cache.js.gz
    86955  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-67fde5fb08b0f134e867.cache.js
    26514  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-67fde5fb08b0f134e867.cache.js.gz
      365  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/index.html
      273  07-29-2022 14:33   META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/index.html.gz
```

But when I load the application, FireFox inspector shows this error:

[image]

Note the reported error loading `http://localhost:8080/pcom/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-67fde5fb08b0f134e867.cache.js`.

That URL is incorrect and generates a 404 error - I can verify this using `curl(1)`.

However I can use `curl(1)` to successfully load the correct URL, which is `http://localhost:8080/pcom/pcom/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-67fde5fb08b0f134e867.cache.js`.

**Why does Vaadin 23 rewrite the URL in the `index.html` file so as to make it unloadable??**

FYI, also filed as [Vaadin Flow Bug #14239](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/14239).

**UPDATE**

Vaadin has [reverted](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/commit/8b3e12b9035e47a2fd25dc400293320a4fb8c9dd) the change which caused this problem. Yay.

Comment: I looks like Vaadin does not recognize pcom url-pattern Why did you add this?

Comment: I added it because that's how I deploy my application. Stop blaming the victim :)

Comment: Ok :-) You have to tell Vaadin that you have a different context path. But I'm confused because you are not setting the context path. but just the path for one servlet PCOM. What is the purpose of this servlet?

Comment: The servlet serves the GUI application. Other "sibling" servlets in the same WAR file do other stuff like handle incoming REST API requests, etc.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or CDI?

Comment: I'm using Spring but not Spring Boot. Here's a demonstration of the problem: https://github.com/archiecobbs/vaadin-flow-bugs/tree/issue-14239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved as in the comments of your reported Vaadin bug.

Add /VAADIN/* to the servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VaadinBugServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/demo/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I'd say "worked around" is a more appropriate verb here than "solved" but yes :)